# ServiceContractGenerator type problem

Tags: web-services

We try to generate web service proxy class using ServiceContractGenerator.
We get problem at using web services that returns DataTable.

Generated code for DataTable below

```
public partial class MethodResultOfDataTableymujubN2Result
{

    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

    private System.Xml.XmlElement any1Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", Order=0)]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1", Order=1)]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement Any1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.any1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.any1Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

References.cs class can handle DataTable, and return DataTable object

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public System.Data.DataTable Result { ...
```

How can we handle DataTable for generating web service proxy class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below method solve the problem

```
WsdlImporter wsdlImporter = CreateWsdlImporter(address);
AddStateForDataContractSerializerImport(wsdlImporter);

...

private void AddStateForDataContractSerializerImport(WsdlImporter importer)
{
    XsdDataContractImporter xsdDataContractImporter = new XsdDataContractImporter();
    xsdDataContractImporter.Options = new ImportOptions();

    xsdDataContractImporter.Options.ImportXmlType = true;
    xsdDataContractImporter.Options.GenerateSerializable = true;
    xsdDataContractImporter.Options.ReferencedTypes.Add(typeof(DataTable));

    importer.State.Add(typeof(XsdDataContractImporter), xsdDataContractImporter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and after investigating I did the following which solved the issue:

- usually you will find two properties in the class causing the error:

  ```
  private System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] anyField;


  private System.Xml.Linq.XElement any1Field;
  ```

What I did was the following:

1- changed the first property from an array to a single value variable as follows

```
private System.Xml.Linq.XElement anyField;
```

2- change the getter and setter methods of this property , to match your changes

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", Order=0)]
    public System.Xml.Linq.XElement Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Any");
        }
    }
```

3- remove or comment out the second property

```
// private System.Xml.Linq.XElement any1Field;
```

4- remove or comment out the second property's getter and setter methods

```
  /*

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1", Order=1)]
        public System.Xml.Linq.XElement Any1 {
            get {
                return this.any1Field;
            }
            set {
                this.any1Field = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Any1");
            }
        }


*/
```

At this point you can now access the resulting XML as follows by calling the "Any" property which will return an xml which you can manipulate :

e.g., in my case it was the following class causing the problems

```
public partial class GetUserBalancesClassAccounts
```

In my method I was able to access the xml as follows

```
GetUserBalancesClassAccounts accts = balances.Accounts;

XElement doc = accts.Any;

foreach( XElement docElement in doc.Elements()){

    foreach (XElement account in docElement.Elements("Account"))

    {

        ... do something ...

    }

}
```